# Subquery in select statement syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run the below query and i keep getting the error:`**ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated**`

```
SELECT
    InnerTable."Cycle ID",
    (
    SELECT REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(CF_ITEM_NAME,'//'),'//','/')
            AS "Path1"
            FROM CYCL_FOLD
            START WITH CF_FATHER_ID = InnerTable."Cycle ID"
            CONNECT BY PRIOR CF_ITEM_ID = CF_FATHER_ID
    ) as "path1",
    InnerTable."CSR/RCQ Name",
    TEST.TS_DESCRIPTION as "Test Case Description",
FROM
(-- few conditions here
) InnerTable INNER JOIN TEST  ON InnerTable."Test Case ID" = TEST.TS_TEST_ID
```

Can any body tell me what is wrong with the syntax..Thanks so much..

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: @sashkello The error is because of the select subquery in select statement, If i remove that part it is working fine...

Comment: You're going in the the direction of isolating the part that is the issue. Now finish it off by isolating the only part within that has quotes. In other words change `REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(CF_ITEM_NAME,'//'),'//','/')` to something harmless like `'TEST'`. It may be that the `/` symbol is escaping quotes or something.

Comment: @ElectricLlama you are right..I guess i solved the problem

Comment: For everyone's benefit please post the solution. Then you can accept it yourself. How many times have you googled something and found the question and not the answer?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you have an odd number of single quotes.

The snippet you posted only contains balanced pairs of quotes - in the REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(CF_ITEM_NAME() chain.   So the problem must lie in the excised part of your query:

```
-- few conditions here
```

Does the redaction include any string literals?  If so check them.

This error is easy to spot with an IDE which supports SQL syntax highlighting.

---

> " i don't find any error with the single or double quotes"

Me neither.  Hmmm.

There is the possibility that the `/` is escaping the quote somehow.  That will depend on you client settings.  In SQL*Plus ESCAPE is off by default and besides the default escape character is `\`.  So your statement would work on my set-up ...

```
SQL> sho escape
escape OFFSQL> select '//' from dual
  2  /

'/
--
//

SQL> c.//./
  1* select '/' from dual
SQL> r
  1* select '/' from dual

'
-
/

SQL> set escape on
SQL> r
  1* select '/' from dual

'
-
/

SQL>
```

... but check your client settings anyway.

Comment: Hi APC, Here is the complete query http://pastebin.com/pEnDy5qU and i don't find any error with the single or double quotes

Comment: APC, Actually i am using HP Quality centre for running this query. When i replace the double quotes with * symbol it is working fine..Not sure why it is behaving..Thanks for your time..